# Max upload size limit 2MB in php even after editting php.ini

Tags: php, upload, max, size

I have v annoying pb that am struggling to resolve. Basically, when i was testing code on localhost it used to give error if i tried uploading image larger than 2M. I have edited php.ini file as advised on other threads and that fixed the problem. However, when i moved exactly same code to AWS EC2 instance, I am again getting same issue.

if i check phpinfo(), that does correctly show

```
post_max_size = 30M
upload_max_filesize = 30M
```

as i would like it to be. I have also restarted apache, httpd and pretty much anything i could think of for any changes to take into effect, but i am still having this issue.

Adding the following bits directly into the code:

```
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '30M');
```

Anyone could help with this please? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

if you’re using unix based system (linux) you may try to create a new file in your root directory(e.g: `var/www` or `public_html`) with this name: `.user.ini` (Exactly this name. Dot at the beginning is required).
Then try to set your values:

```
post_max_size = 30M
upload_max_filesize = 30M
```

Comment: thanks, but doesnt seem to be working

Comment: On amazon linux 2023 this solution worked perfectly. Previously I set in php.in and .htaccess but it was not working.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

These directives don't work if only present in php files.
They **must** be in php.ini and you have to RESTART apache to work.

Edit the php.ini in /etc/php/version/apache2, save and restart:

```
 max_execution_time  = 30  #seconds
 post_max_size = 30M
 upload_max_filesize = 30M
```